# Finding the area of the sector in the disc cut out by two rays.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles, area

Working on the book: Lange, Serge. "Basic Mathematics" (p. 119, exercise 1).

[image]

Finding the area of the sector determined by the angle in exercise **a** (area of disc is $60in^2)$:

Let $S$ be the sector determined by $A$ in the disc $D$ centered at $P$. Let $A_S$ and $A_D$ denote area of sector $S$ and disc $D$, respectively. I proceed to calculate the area of sector S:

$
\begin{align*}
\frac{A_S}{A_D}&=\frac{60°}{360°}\\
A_S&=\frac{60°\cdot60in^2}{360°}=10in^2
\end{align*}
$

The author solution is $1in^2$.

What's the correct answer ?

Comment: Recall that the area of the sector with angle $\theta$ and radius $r$ is given by $a = \frac 1 2 \theta r^2.$ Ultimately, this gives that $\frac{a_S}{a_D} = \frac{\theta_S}{\theta_D}$ so that $a_S = \frac{\theta_S}{\theta_D} a_D = \frac 1 6 60 = 10.$ I believe that the author made a typographical error in his solution.

Comment: Thank you. Exercise b answer is: 2 square inches instead of 20. It’s surprising that every answer is off by a factor of 10.

Comment: Why is $1/2$ in your formula for the area of a sector with a given angle ?

Comment: Compare to the area $\pi r^2$ of a circle of radius $r > 0.$ Of course, the circle is just the sector with $\theta = 2 \pi,$ so $\pi r^2 = \frac{1}{2}(2 \pi) r^2 = \frac{1}{2} \theta r^2.$

Comment: Recall that the sector length is given by $s(r) = r \theta.$ It might not mean anything to you now, but we can obtain the sector area by taking $a(r) = \int_0^r s(x) \, dx = \int_0^r x \theta \, dr = \frac{1}{2} \theta r^2.$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Probably the error is because the author solved for a disk of area $6 \text{ in}^2$ instead of $60 \text{ in}^2$. Whether the error was the addition of the $0$ or the dropping of a decimal point, I cannot say.

Comment: That book, by the way, is known to have more errors than most texts.  Lange was sort of famous for knocking out textbooks in one day.  Quality control was often lacking.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It’s not the first time I wondered why I couldn’t get the solution given by the author.